# Administrative Virus Scan over Network

Tags: administrator, malware

Is it possible to run a virus or other type of malware scan over multiple computers at once?

For example if there are ~30 computers in a network that I need to run Spy-Bot Search and Destroy on at once without logging into each of them individually how would I do this?

Additionally can this be done while another user is logged in or if no users are logged in (sort of like as a background process?) The machines are running Windows XP.

Comment: So from what I understand is that I can only scan shared folders/files -- not the entire machine (system memory ect). Would I be able to schedule a virus scan as a task but with admin privileges and have it run in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no actual way to scan a whole network of computers. If you have mapped network drives, you can scan through those yes. So basically if you have a large amount of roaming profiles/network profiles, you can run a scan for those individual profiles all at the same time.

Comment: So you're saying I could go to "My Network Places" and view all of the computers that way and scan them?

Comment: If they contain items that can be scanned like a shared My Documents, My Pictures, etc.

Comment: SuperAntiSpyware/Malwarebytes might allow you to do it.

Comment: Nice thanks! So from what I understand is that I can only scan shared folders/files -- not the entire machine (system memory ect). Would I be able to schedule a virus scan as a task but with admin privileges and have it run in the background?

Comment: SuperAntiSpyware has a timed scan and it will run in the background. You can open it while it's scanning using the tray icon in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is can I install SuperAntiSpyware on multiple computers and have it run at x time as admin (whether or not the user logged in has admin rights)?

Comment: Symantec Endpoint Protection would be best suited for that. It's what we use at the college I work at and it allows for a scan even though the user has no admin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any number of Anti-virus apps like Symantec Endpoint Protection to do this.  I belive Adaware has a version that will do network scans. With 30 systems a maanged product would be an excellent choice.

Any non-retail AV solution should be able to do this easily.  Not free but easily managed,updated and monitored which is important.

Since all systems should have AV protection, a managed solution fits perfectly